# LINQ C# - Select with group by and count to compare two entities based on count

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two entities that both have the same ID columns as shown in below table "A":

```
| CategoryID | ProductID |
|------------|-----------|
| 1          | 4         |
| 1          | 5         |
| 2          | 7         |
```

In a LINQ statement I want to only select objects from table A where the count of ProductIDs grouped by the CategoryID (on both tables) is less in table B.

So in above table the group by count for CategoryID 1 is two. If the same CategoryID exists in table B and has only one ProductID based on the group by count then retrieve the object.

I hope you can mock up some example how this can be done. Maybe in one Where statement or multiple variables.

Thank you.

**Update**: here is what I have. I forgot to mention that the tables need to be loaded from **different repositories**.

```
var categoriesToLoad = new List<int>();

// table A
var tableACount = repo.ReadAll()
     .GroupBy(n => n.CategoryID)
     .Select(n => new
     {
         CategoryID = n.Key,
         CountA = n.Count()
     }
     )
     .OrderBy(n => n.CategoryID);

// table B
var tableBCount = repoTableB.ReadAll()
      .GroupBy(n => n.CategoryID)
      .Select(n => new
      {
          CategoryID = n.Key,
          CountB = n.Count()
      }
      )
  .OrderBy(n => n.CategoryID);

// check count
foreach (var itemTableATableB in tableBCount)
{
    foreach (var itemTableA in tableACount)
    {
        if (itemTableA.CategoryID == itemTableATableB.CategoryID && itemTableA.CountA < itemTableATableB.CountB)
        {
            categoriesToLoad.Add((int)itemTableATableB.CategoryID);
        }
    }
}

var test = myRepo.ReadAll().Where(t => categoriesToLoad.Contains(t.Category_id))
```

Besides the quiet long code, due to the  `if (itemTableA.CategoryID == itemTableATableB.CategoryID` 
I am also losing values because some Category IDs in table B do not exist in table A (but I need those too).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication87
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
           dt1.Columns.Add("CategoryID", typeof(int));
           dt1.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(int));

           dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,4});
           dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,5});
           dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2,7});

           DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
           dt2.Columns.Add("CategoryID", typeof(int));
           dt2.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(int));

           dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 4 });
           dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 7 });

           var lessRows = (from a in dt1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("CategoryID"))
                                     join b in dt2.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("CategoryID")) on a.Key equals b.Key
                                     select new { a = a, b = b })
                                     .Where(x => x.a.Count() > x.b.Count())
                                     .ToList();

        }
    }



}
```